# How do I use the remainder?

Tags: java

I have a problem to solve!

Create a program that asks the user for a number and tells whether the number is even or odd.

Type a number: 2
Number 2 is even.

Type a number: 7
Number 7 is odd.

Hint: The number's remainder when dividing by 2 tells whether the number is even or odd. The remainder can be obtained with the % operator.

I wrote this code but I'm stuck:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenOrOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Type your program here

        System.out.print("Type a number: ");
         int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
         System.out.println("");

    if (number % 2 == 0); 
         System.out.println("Number" + number + " is even.");

         else {
    System.out.println("Number" + number + " is odd.");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;` terminates the statement. You have mistakenly used it in your `if`. Fix it to:

```
if (number % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Number" + number + " is even.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Number" + number + " is odd.");
}
```

Comment: damn your faster typing speed :P

Comment: U fixed my code with that semicolon ;), thank a lot! U made my day. Ur cool. Can i ask u something else?